# Stable Rotation Setup for Experiments (table version)

Tags: experimental-physics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I am looking for a rotation devise like that one in this video below (from 00:40 seconds). Does anyone know where to get one, or have any idea about how to create a nice and stable rotation setup for experiments without too much hassle and DIY? 
https://youtu.be/CHQOctEvtTY